# Como pegar um elemento dentro de um iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

Porque não funciona `.contents()`?
Como pegar um elemento dentro de um iframe como no exemplo da jQuery API

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já disseram você não pode acessar o conteúdo de um `frame` ou `iframe` de outro domínio via Javascript por questões de segurança.

O exemplo que você colocou no Plunker não funcionou porque o domínio onde o código é executado é `run.plnkr.co`, sendo que a URL do `iframe` é `plnkr.co`. Ou seja, mesmo subdomínios são considerados domínios diferentes.

Fiz um [*fork* funcional do seu Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/kvi2xaoMGI7vFtPcIf7w/preview) criando um HTML no mesmo diretório e colocando-o no `iframe`.

Note ainda que usei o evento `load()` para aguardar o carregamento da página o `iframe`.

Answer (score 4):

De fato, não é possivel trabalhar o conteúdo de um iframe que esteja em um dominio diferente da pagina que o renderizou. Porém, para solucionar esse problema de troca de mensagens, existe o jquery-postmessage-plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/), dependendo da sua necessidade ele pode ser utilizado.

Ele é citado em varios exemplos na internet para resolver problemas do tipo que você citou.

Comment: Valeu amigo, na verdade preciso inserir uma classe em uma div que esta dentro do iframe. Inclusive o domínio do iframe é o mesmo. Porem não esta funcionando como falei acima.

Comment: @WeslleyOliveira O console do navegador está mostrando algma mensagem de erro? Ou está apenas "falhando silenciosamente"? E em qual navegador você está testando?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Então estou trabalhando dentro do ambiente c9.io, e usando o chrome de navegador, mais não da nenhum erro. "falhando silenciosamente".

Comment: @WeslleyOliveira É, a princípio era pra estar funcionando... Sugiro tentar isolar mais o erro: experimenta fazer `console.log` em: a) `$( "#frameDemo" )`; b) `$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" )` **antes de chamar o `css`**; c) depois de chamar. Edite sua resposta com esses detalhes.

Comment: Seu problema pode estar no c9.io, ja realizou testes no seu navegador diretamente ?

Comment: Mgibsonbr então amigo, já fiz todos esses testes de mesa, e infelizmente nada, estou me matando com essa duvida, obrigado pela força. Mas deve ter haver com o http://c9.io mesmo, como diz nosso amigo @MauroAlexandre. Só que já testei no http://plnkr.co/, e não rolou, Vou retomar os testes.

Comment: Olha amigos http://embed.plnkr.co/yiPDhc/preview confiram o exemplo, que não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Você até consegue efetuar uma troca de mensagens entre a página pai e o iframe.
Só que, para isto, você precisa ter acesso ao código fonte do iframe.
Se você tem este acesso, tenho alguns exemplos que podem te ajudar (precisei fazer isso várias vezes). Caso não tenha, por questões de segurança você realmente não vai conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Você só pode manipular iframes que estão no mesmo domínio, ou alterando os headers do iframe pelo servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode buscar dados de domínios externos usando jquery. Experimente a [biblioteca curl](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) do PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode manipular dessa forma:

```
jQuery(“.iframeMain”, window.parent.document)
```

confira o site com o [exemplo](http://codificando.tumblr.com/post/16815760816/manipulando-iframe-com-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

O acesso a `iframes` e `frames` só é possível quando o domínio por inteiro é igual (isto incluí subdomínio e porta). Caso um desses seja diferente seu browser vai ignorar qualquer acesso ao DOM do alvo, considerando uma falha de segurança.

É possível comunicar usando o `window.postMessage` descrito no HTML5, porém browsers mais antigos não suportam tal recurso.

Você pode ler mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage que também contém uma referencia para os browsers que suportam o recurso e suas limitações.

Uma observação sobre o seu código é que ele também pode estar sendo executado antes do DOM do seu `iframe` ser renderizado. O iframe tem carregamento assincronomo em relação ao window em que está, então para garantir que o elemento exista no seu frame, aguarde pelo evento `load` do `iframe` para fazer a busca no DOM. (lembrando que os domínios tem que ser idênticos)